# Fetch method put with React.js and Node server

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs

I want to update my data in my MySQL database. I have React front-end and I'm using node server as back-end. I am getting nothing with body when I try to update data with fetch put method. Why is that?

Why does "body" in fetch method with JSON.stringify(req.body) give me an empty object server-side?

React code(button click event):

```
handlePrioDown(a) {
        sessionStorage["id"] = a["id"];
        sessionStorage["priority"] = a["priority"];


        fetch('http://localhost:3001/TeacherPri/'+a["id"], { 
            method: 'PUT',
            body: JSON.stringify({priority: a["priority"]+1})
        })
}
```

Node (server.js):

```
//CORS middleware
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

    next();
}
app.use( bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}))
app.use(allowCrossDomain)

app.use(express.json())

app.route("/TeacherPri/:id")
    .put(controller.changePriority)
```

Node (controller.js):

```
changePriority: (req ,res) => {
        let v = req.body;
        let key = req.params.id;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(v) + " ::::: id="+key)
        CONN.query('UPDATE teacher SET priority=? WHERE id=?', [v.priority, key],
            (err, results, fields) => {
                if(err) {
                    console.log(err)
                    res.json(err)
                } else {
                    console.log("Done")
                    res.statusCode = 204
                    res.send();
                }
            })
    }
```

I'm excpecting that I get something like { priority: 4 } as req.body object on server side. I get empty object atm.

Comment: Can you check in the network tab of chrome if what you're sending is what you want to send and take a look at the details of headers, response etc?

Comment: Try setting Content Type header in fetch() request

Comment: @charlietfl I tried to set header in fetch and nothing changed. I also already have headers set in node also